# how to check that is null?

Tags: asp.net, null, isnull, isnullorempty

I have the following code in aspx file. I would like to display a message when my query returns 0 rows or null. How can I check this correct since my example does not catch null values.

```
        protected void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchItem;
        searchItem = "Select * FROM test WHERE (name like '%"+searchTxt.Text.ToString()+"%')";
        SqlDataSource.SelectCommand = searchItem;    
        if (SqlDataSource.SelectCommand == null)
            hiddenMsg.Visible = true;
        else
            SqlDataSource.SelectCommand = searchItem;

    }
```

Comment: Look into `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: What `null` are you trying to catch here? The `searchItem` string will never be `null` where you test for it.

Comment: how can I check the SqlDataSource.SelectCommand for null values ?

Comment: Try using the `string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)` method.

Comment: Do you mean the _results_ of running the query? Are you looking for 0 results, of whether any of the fields in the result set is `null`?

Comment: I am searching for 0 returned rows after running the query

Comment: Where is the code which sets up a sql connection and executes the sql in your selectcommand?

Comment: in the page load, it works correctly and return some rows if the items exist, however it never catch the fact that the query returns 0 rows, no item exists

Comment: the hidden message is never displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        if (count == 0)
        {
             display your message that no rows returned
        }
        else {
           display rows returned
       }
```

enjoy